# JavaFX buttons have annoying gaps around them

Tags: css, javafx

I've configured a JavaFX button to change colour when pressed using a CSS pseudo class (.button:pressed). However, while the button changes colour, a small gap of the old colour is still visible between the top of the button and the button border. This image illustrates the problem - there is a small slither of light grey between the depressed button and the upper button border [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tujK1.png)

How can I fix this?

EDIT: When I change the width of the border for each button, the problem is more clearly visible. There are gaps around every button, and when the button has focus (was pressed last) the lower border gap is filled in  - in this picture, the number 8. [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwe4c.png)

```
package calculator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.*;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Calculator extends Application {

    private static int appWidth = 230*3;
    private static int appHeight = 300*3;
    private static int numRows = 7;
    private static int numCols = 8;
    List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
//Create 0-9 buttons 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Button tempButton = new Button(Integer.toString(i));
            tempButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            HBox.setHgrow(tempButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
            VBox.setVgrow(tempButton, Priority.ALWAYS);
            buttonList.add(tempButton);
        }

//Point button 
        //point button 
        Button point = new Button(".");
        point.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Plus, plys, minus, multiply, and divide buttons 
        Button equals = new Button("=");
        equals.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        equals.getStyleClass().add("button-special");

        Button plus = new Button("+");
        plus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        plus.getStyleClass().add("button-special");

        Button minus = new Button("-");
        minus.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        minus.getStyleClass().add("button-special");

        Button multiply = new Button("x");
        multiply.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        multiply.getStyleClass().add("button-special");

        Button divide = new Button("/");
        divide.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        divide.getStyleClass().add("button-special");

//Clear and delete buttons 
        Button clear = new Button("C");
        clear.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        Button del = new Button("Del");
        del.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Screen s 
        Label screen = new Label("0");
        screen.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        screen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

//Create GridPane 
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

//Add nodes to grid pane 
        grid.add(buttonList.get(0), 0, 6, 4, 1);
        grid.add(point, 4, 6, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(1), 0, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(2), 2, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(3), 4, 5, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(4), 0, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(5), 2, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(6), 4, 4, 2, 1);

        grid.add(buttonList.get(7), 0, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(8), 2, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(buttonList.get(9), 4, 3, 2, 1);

        grid.add(equals, 6, 6, 2, 1);
        grid.add(plus, 6, 5, 2, 1);
        grid.add(minus, 6, 4, 2, 1);
        grid.add(multiply, 6, 3, 2, 1);
        grid.add(divide, 6, 2, 2, 1);

        grid.add(clear, 0, 2, 3, 1);
        grid.add(del, 3, 2, 3, 1);

//Set row and column constraints 
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < Calculator.numRows; rowIndex++) {
            RowConstraints rc = new RowConstraints();
            rc.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            rc.setFillHeight(true);
            rc.setPercentHeight(Calculator.appHeight / Calculator.numRows);
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(rc);
        }

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < Calculator.numCols; colIndex++) {
            ColumnConstraints cc = new ColumnConstraints();
            cc.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
            cc.setFillWidth(true);
            cc.setPercentWidth(Calculator.appWidth / Calculator.numCols);
            grid.getColumnConstraints().add(cc);
        }

// Create the scene and the stage 
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, appWidth, appHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("Simple.css");

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //primaryStage.setTitle("Calculator");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.root
{
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;

}

.button
{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
    -fx-border-color: gray;
    -fx-border-width: .3;
    -fx-background-color: #E0E0E0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;

}

.button:pressed
{
    -fx-background-color: #B2B2B2;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;

}

.button-special
{
    -fx-background-color: #EA9747;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 17pt;

}

.button-special:pressed
{
    -fx-background-color: #bb8738;
    -fx-text-fill: #555555;
    -fx-border-color: gray;

}

.button-top
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to add specific background and border styles:

```
-fx-border-width: 0 1 1 0;
-fx-background-insets: 0,1,1;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
```